# Is there a way to do variadic recursive currying in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, currying

I know that there probably wouldn't be any reason to use this over some other way of creating a variadic function, but is it semantically possible to define something to do this? For example, it could be called like `sum(1)(2)(3)();`. I attempted to implement it with the following code:

```
function sum(x) {
    return function(y) {
        if (!y) return 0;
        else return x + sum(y);
    };
}
```

However, when called this gives `TypeError: string is not a function`. What would cause this to return a string? When I inspected it more closely, it looked like it was returning the code for the function as a string, which makes no sense to me. That said, I am not extensively familiar with the semantics of intricate JavaScript, so I could be missing some huge concept in it.

Comment: `sum(1)(2)` returns `String` `"1function (y) {
        if (!y) return 0;
        else return x + sum(y);
    }"` `console.log(typeof sum(1)(2)(3))`, `sum(1)(2)(3)` returns `TypeError: string is not a function` What is expected result ?

Comment: EDIT: responding to your edit:
sum(1)(2) should return a function that, when called with no arguments, would return 0 (or, alternatively, would return another function if given arguments). Then, this function would be used to make the expression 1 + 2 + 0, or 3.


The expected result is for `sum(1)(2)(3)();` would be 6, since `sum(1)` would return a function to be called with 2, which would become 1 + sum(2) which would do the same thing (2 + sum(3)) which would become 3 + 0, returning 3, returning 5, returning 6. (jeez, that's hard to explain)

Comment: Since `sum` returns a function, `x + sum(y)` will convert that function to a string and perform string concatenation. *"sum(1)(2) should return a function"* but the inner function never returns a function itself. It either returns `0` or `x + sum(y)`.

Comment: Why wouldn't `sum(y)` call the function recursively? `x + sum(y)` as an expression should reduce to an integer.

Comment: *"Why wouldn't `sum(y)` call the function recursively?"* It does call `sum` of course. But `sum` returns a *function*. It's unclear how `number + function` should become a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `x` is a number and `sum(y)` is a function. Using the `+` operator on them uses their gcd type which are strings, and cannot be called.

You cannot curry operators in javascript. You need to return a curried function explicitly, and tell it when to calculate the values. An appropriate fix for our function would be

```
function sum(x) {
    return function(y) {
        if (!y) return x;
//                     ^
        else return sum(x + y);
//                      ^^^
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(1) -> ref Function(y)
sum(1)(2) -> invocation Function(2)
Function(2) -> 1 + (sum(y) -> sum(2) -> ref Function(y))
```

Now, `1 + (ref Function(y))`, as you can see, you're adding a number and a reference.

The javascript is thinking that you're trying to concatenate, hence it calls `ToString` method of `Function`, internally, which gives the function body as a string.

So, the next time you call, you're calling on a String and hence the error as String isn't a function.

A correct code would be what Bergi has implemented.

Comment: Your code doesn't really work. `var addOne = add(1); addOne(3)(); // 4` but `addOne(1)() // 5`???

Comment: @Bergi don't know how. But it works for me. And why did you leave the invocation on `add(1)`?

Comment: Oh right I didn't realize how wrong you've done it, and didn't try out the counterexample. The last one does yield `1` not `5`, which is still not the expected `2`. A much easier counterexample: `var getOne = add(1); getOne(); // 1 getOne() // 0???`. The sum expression [should not change depending on how often it is evaluated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science))…